# What is an auto trait in Rust?

Tags: rust

Trying to solve the problem described in [Trait bound Sized is not satisfied for Sized trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710684/trait-bound-sized-is-not-satisfied-for-sized-trait), I found the following code gives the following error:

```
trait SizedTrait: Sized {
    fn me() -> Self;
}

trait AnotherTrait: Sized {
    fn another_me() -> Self;
}

impl AnotherTrait for SizedTrait + Sized {
    fn another_me() {
        Self::me()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/main.rs:9:36
  |
9 | impl AnotherTrait for SizedTrait + Sized {
  |                                    ^^^^^ non-auto additional trait
```

But the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition) does not mention `auto trait` at all.

What is an auto trait in Rust and how does it differ from a non-auto trait?

Comment: I think it would be any trait that is automatically implemented, it's certainly the case for `Sized`, but I wonder if this would apply to `Send` and `Sync`...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think `Sized` might be even more special than `Send` and `Sync`...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

An *auto trait* is the new name for the terribly named<sup>1</sup> *opt-in, built-in trait* (OIBIT).

These are an unstable feature where a trait is automatically implemented for every type unless they opt-out or contain a value that does not implement the trait:

```
#![feature(optin_builtin_traits)]

auto trait IsCool {}

// Everyone knows that `String`s just aren't cool
impl !IsCool for String {}

struct MyStruct;
struct HasAString(String);

fn check_cool<C: IsCool>(_: C) {}

fn main() {
    check_cool(42);
    check_cool(false);
    check_cool(MyStruct);
    
    // the trait bound `std::string::String: IsCool` is not satisfied
    // check_cool(String::new());
    
    // the trait bound `std::string::String: IsCool` is not satisfied in `HasAString`
    // check_cool(HasAString(String::new()));
}
```

Familiar examples include [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html):

```
pub unsafe auto trait Send { }
pub unsafe auto trait Sync { }
```

Further information is available in the [Unstable Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/auto-traits.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> These traits are neither opt-in (they are opt-out) nor necessarily built-in (user code using nightly may use them). Of the 5 words in their name, 4 were outright lies.

Comment: I totally agree that the name of this feature is confusing. It's just caught me out (I was trying to opt *out* of `Send`). Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: what is the current state of this feature? I have a trait `Render` which should be implemented by everything which implements `Display`.

Comment: @nuiun: I found out how to do this: `impl<D: Display> Render for D {...}`