# Will a PhantomPinned member make my struct have a fixed memory address?

Tags: memory, rust, move-semantics

I'm writing Rust code which communicates with a C API, and I need a certain struct to have a fixed memory address. So far, I found:

- [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html) for pointers;
- [`pin_mut`](https://docs.rs/pin-utils/latest/pin_utils/macro.pin_mut.html) macro to pin on the stack;
- [`PhantomPinned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomPinned.html), which is not clear to me.

If I understood correctly, `PhantomPinned` would be the easiest to use: just having it as a member would make my struct automatically have a fixed memory address. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is `Pin`. It's a pointer that keeps your object from being moved.

`pin_mut!()` is just a macro that helps you create a `Pin` instance without heap allocation or `unsafe` code.

`PhantomPinned` has another, though related, goal. By default, your type will implement the [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html) trait (unless it contains a type that don't implement `Unpin`, however most types do). This is problematic, because for types that implements `Unpin`, `Pin` has no effect: it does not prevent you from moving them. This is because most types do not need a fixed memory address. Think about `i32`, for example: even if you create `Pin<&mut i32>`, you can move it, because `i32` implements `Unpin`, because even if you'll move it nothing bad will happen, and no data will be validated.

So for `Pin` to be effective you need to un-impl `Unpin`. This is done by either including a field that doesn't implements `Unpin` itself as a field, or having a negative impl (see [What is an auto trait in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710852/what-is-an-auto-trait-in-rust)):

```rust
impl !Unpin for MyType {}
```

Unfortunately, negative impls are unstable. Instead, the standard library provides the `PhantomPinned` type, which is costless (a ZST), but doesn't implement `Unpin` (it has a negative impl, since the standard library is allowed to use unstable features it can do that). And now when your type includes it it becomes `!Unpin` too.

To sum up, you need to include `PhantomPinned` in your struct so it will not be `Unpin`, and you need to wrap it in `Pin` so it will be unmovable.

Comment: So "not being `Unpin`" and "unmovable" are different things? Could you expand further on this?

Comment: "Not being `Unpin`" means "_can_ be unmovable". It will be movable without `Pin`, but `Unpin` types will be movable even with `Pin`.

Answer (score 1):

The only unmoveable value in Rust is the value in `Pin<T>` and only if `T` does not implement `Unpin`.

`T` may be a reference or some smart pointer type like `Box` or `Arc`, but `Pin` is needed to specify that the value may not move.

`Unpin` is a trait implemented for types that don't care if they are moved, even if they are pinned. It's a marker trait automatically implemented for all types whose members all implement `Unpin`. `PhantomPinned` is a simple, zero sized type that does *not* implement `Unpin`, so it may be added to a struct or enum to make it not automatically implement `Unpin`.

Note that `Unpin` is only relevant to `Pin` wrapped values - values outside of `Pin` can still be moved. Operations requiring the value not be moved should take a `Pin<&mut T>` instead of `&mut T`.

`pin_mut` is a macro for converting a stack value to a pinned pointer. It's just a convenience for a known-safe case and doesn't really play into how `Pin` works.

---

So for your case, it sounds like your structure should have a `PhantomPinned` member, and all of its operations should take a pin-wrapped reference.